# Fetch nth row onwards in informix SQL query

Tags: sql, informix

I have a large data set where I want to select the nth row onwards. Database is informix and `rownumber` is not supported. I used `rowid` but that does not give correct result.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to look up the SKIP keyword in the Informix SQL Syntax manual on SELECT statements.  I'm no longer sure where the online URLs are — they've hidden them from me (or I'm just more obtuse than the average Informix user).

If you want to start from the 100th row, you'd specify:

```
SELECT SKIP 99 …
  FROM …
```